# Change css of specific clicked element with React.js

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, target

This is my first question here, so sorry if this looks a bit confusing.
I'm developing an application in React.js in my internship and currently struggling with e.target to apply the CSS changes. This is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Line extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display: 'block',
            border: 0
        };
        this.changeDisplay = this.changeDisplay.bind(this);
        this.showCircle = this.showCircle.bind(this);
    }

    changeDisplay() {
        const newDisplay = this.state.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
        this.setState({ display: newDisplay });
    }

    showCircle(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        const newCircle = this.state.border == 0 ? '2px solid #2B3438' : 0;
        this.setState({
            border: newCircle
        });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div style={{ display: this.state.display }}>
                <button id="Cross" onClick={this.changeDisplay}>&#10005;</button>
                <div id="Line">
                    <div id="InsideLine">
                        <img src="../../../ic/icon-linha.svg" />
                        <p>Line</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="circle" id="one" onClick={(e) => this.showCircle(e)} style={{ border: this.state.border }}></div>
                    <div className="circle" id="two" onClick={(e) => this.showCircle(e)} style={{ border: this.state.border }}></div>
                    <div className="circle" id="three"></div>
                    <div className="circle" id="four"></div>
                    <div className="circle" id="five"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the function 'showCircle(e)', I can return from the console.log the element I just clicked as you can see in the following image:
[console.log has return clicked div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grGU3.jpg)

My doubt is: I don't really know where to put the e.target to do the changes inside the 'showCircle' function. I replaced 'this.' with 'e./e.target' and it doesn't work.

Btw, the function showCircles works, it changes the border but in all div's that call the 'showCircles' function on click.

**The goal is to appear that border around the clicked color so the user knows where he just clicked.**

Comment: I think you are going to want to grab the ID for the element and update the state based on that.

something along the lines of
this.setState({[e.target.id.border]: newCircle});

Comment: the above should be "this.setState({[e.target.border]: newCircle});"

Comment: Nothing changed, he does know what to target, but it doesn't change its state at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it feasible to have a state for each circle? Something like that might work:

```
state = {
    circles: {
        one: 0,
        two: 0,
        three: 0,
        // (...)
    }
}

showCircle = (e) => {
    let id = e.target.id
    let circles = this.state.circles

    if (circles[id] !== 0) {
        circles[id] = 0
    } else {
        Object.keys(circles).forEach(c => circles[c] = 0) // Resets to initial styling
        circles[id] = '2px solid #2B3438'
    }

    this.setState({
        circles: circles,
    });
}
```

Then just slightly change your rendered div (btw you don't need to pass the event as a parameter).

```
<div 
    className="circle" 
    id="one" 
    onClick={this.showCircle} 
    style={{ border: this.state.circles.one}}>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really necessary, the event argument is automatically forwarded.

Comment: oh i didn't know that :o

Comment: when I click in 'one' it returns 'one' has undefined "style={{ border: this.state.circles.one}}>"

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Did you include the "circles" object in your state?

Comment: Now it works, it was missing a comma, sorry. But now when selecting another circle, the before selected remains with the 2px border.

Comment: My bad, just add it back: `circles[id] = circles[id] === 'block' ? '2px solid #2B3438' : 'block'`.

Comment: Imagine, I clicked on 'one', and it gets selected, but when I click on 'two', two gets also selected but 'one' doesn't get unselected.
The code is currently like this:

`showCircle(e) {
        let id = e.target.id
        let circles = this.state.circles

        if (circles[id] === 0) {
            circles[id] = '2px solid #2B3438'
        } else if (circles[id] === '2px solid #2B3438') {
            circles[id] = 0
        }
         
        this.setState({
            circles: circles
        });
    }`

Comment: Edited the showCircle function slightly to reflect this. See if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be another approach to the problem apart from the one Felipe suggested

You will have the same behaviour for all those `divs` because you haven't treated those entities as different entities.

In order to make them different, you need to assign them different variables by which you can identify what `div` are you referring to.

For example.

```
showCircle(divClicked) { if(divClicked=='circleone') {this.setState({cricleone: true}) }}
```

Then in your render you can have two styles, activate either one depending on which state variable is true.